# Setting up Laravel project with Git

Tags: php, git, laravel

I'm pretty new to using git, and I wanted to figure out the "best practice" way of setting up a laravel project in my own repo and still be able to fetch updates from the main project (https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git) and merge them with my project?

Could anybody walk me through this with step by step commands?

I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can 'fork' the laravel repository

Comment: Will I be able to fetch updates from the original repo and merge with mine this way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Laravel default app (https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git) doesn't change much and when it changes, Taylor gives the steps to migrate it. What you really want to do is to keep your project in sync with https://github.com/laravel/framework.git, for that you just have to

```
composer update
```

Every day.

But if you really want to have default app in sync too, here are some steps:

1) Go to github and fork https://github.com/laravel/framework.git.

2) Install your application as you would normally:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

3) Rename git origin to anything else:

```
git remote rename origin laravel
```

4) Create a new project on github and add it as your new origin

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/you/yourproject.git
```

5) Add, commit and push it:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin master
```

And you should be good to go.

Every time you need to merge yours with Laravel's you'll probably need to:

1) Fetch the changes

```
 git fetch laravel
```

2) Take a look at the list of branches:

```
git branch -va
```

3) Merge yous with laravel

```
git merge laravel/master
```

Comment: I'm creating a project with this command: composer create-project apiato/apiato apiato --prefer-dist

Problem is that this doesn't have git repo there is no origin to be renamed?

Comment: Yes, it feels like a step may be missing here, plus the two repositories are quite different (the composer pulled, and the laravel/framework repositories).

Answer (score 7):

**How to Setup a Remote Repository with your Laravel Projects:**

Create a *"remote"* repository either using *github*, *bitbucket*, etc. Make sure that the repository your creating is *"empty"* meaning literary empty don't include any *Readme.md* yet.

Create your laravel project file:
*$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-app*
 then *cd my-app* to the project's root folder.

Git Initilization:

$ git init
$ git remote add <name-of-remote> <remote-path>
*ex: git remote add origin  https://github.com/youraccount/my-app.git*
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
$ git push origin master

then, check out your *"remote repository"* if your commits are reflected.

Next step would be to read up on setting up *ssh keys*:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

To know more about *git commands:*
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 5):

Use composer when installing laravel. Here is the workflow that you should follow:

- install laravel using composer
- create your git repo from the above installation
- start developing your application, commit, push, etc.
- when you want to take the latest changes from laravel just use composer again: composer update, your vendor folder will be updated automatically. Be aware that the vendor folder is ignored by git, in this way you will have a clean commit history that will include only your application commits without the laravel ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try using `Fork`, `Sourcetree` or `GitKraken` if you want to have some user interface when doing versioning control with your project. You will not use anymore `git commands` if you have it in your machine.